# How to translate date with Twig and format_date filter?

Tags: symfony, twig

With Twig, I use `format_date` filter. `twig/twig` `twig/intl-extra` `symfony/twig-bundle` are installed.

In my development environment, on my computer, I have this :

```
> 1 août 2021
```

In my production environment, on my server, I have this :

```
> Aug 1, 2021
```

How do I make sure that the date is displayed in French in production ?

In my translation.yaml, I have this :

```
framework:
    default_locale: fr
```

And in twig template, I have this :

```
    {{ app.request.locale }} // return "fr"
    {{ app.request.defaultLocale }} // return "fr"
```